# Verify alias for custom domain on outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-on-the-web

Much like a previous question: [Add email alias for custom domain with out verification](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41572/add-email-alias-for-custom-domain-with-out-verification), how can I verify the alias `fullname@example.com` under the account `name@example.com` when the alias is not an email account?

Contrary to what [the previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/41573/45257) suggests, the email is nowhere to be seen in the `name@example.com` inbox (as expected, surely?).

It's crazy that you need to verify an alias on the same domain. Is there any other way to have email from `fullname@example.com` forwarded to my primary address, **without having to**:

1. Create another account and configure forwarding (which expires after 365 days without login), or;
2. Temporarily change MX records to another mail server in order to pick up mail for `fullname@example.com`.